# Post data from an array to a database

Tags: php, sql, arrays, database, data-structures

I've got two tables in my database, one containing groups and one containing users. The users can be a member of those groups even multiple times.

So users contains "id", "name", "lastname", "group", and some others which are not important atm. The table groups contain just an id and a group name. Those groups are dynamic, sometimes a group gets added, and sometimes a group gets deleted.

On the front end, people can add themselves to a group using a form with a select multiple

But I do not get any further than this. I'm facing two issues. data collected from an  are in an array, so putting them in a SQL query isn't plain simple. (i was thinking to put al the info from the array into just one variable separated by ",") on the other hand, maybe this table format isn't the best way to do so.

So what I'm I asking from you guys. Is it better to change the table structure and into what?
How do I combine an array into one variable so I can put them in the database (separated by ",")<\s>

EDIT!: As recommended by Andy Hall, I 'v created a new table. 
werkgroep_user with id, werkgroep_id, and user_id.

this is what my select looks like

```
<select id="testwerkgroep" name="testwerkgroep[]" multiple>
 <option value="">geen werkgroep</option>
 <option value="1">werkgroep 1</option>
 <option value="2">werkgroep 2</option>
</select>
```

Now I'm facing the problem of getting data from the DB. I want for example all users(name) and their groups(name)

Comment: Can you edit your post with what you've tried?

Comment: `this table format isn't the best way to do so` is correct. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad To answer `How do i combine an array into one variable so i can put them in the database (separated by ",")` though would be `implode`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your Users and Groups tables have a many-to-many relationship. "Many users can be part of many groups".

Without resolving the many-to-many relationship with an intermediary table, you can certainly use a string of comma separated values in the `users.group` field. You would achieve that by using the `implode()` function on your array of group IDs:

`$commaSeparatedGroupIdString = implode($groupIdArray);`

And when you retrieve from the database, you can explode them back out to an array:

`$groupIdArray = explode($commaSeparatedGroupIdString, ",");`

The second (and, I would say **better**) method is to resolve the many-to-many relationship with an intermediary table. This table could be named something like `group_assignments`. One `user` may have many `group_assignments`, and one `group` may have many `group_assignments`.

The structure of the `group_assignment` table would be:

`id` primary key

`user_id` foreign key to the `users.id` field

`group_id` foreign key to the `groups.id` field

Whenever a user wishes to assign themselves to a group, they would make a submission, and your application would create a new record in the `group_assignments` table with the ID of the user and ID of the group they submitted to assign themselves to. Retrieving group assignment information for a user would then require the use of a `JOIN` in your SQL to grab all the associated `group_assignment` records to your user. Removing an assignment is as simple as removing the appropriate record in the `group_assignments` table.

Comment: Alright i will try the better option in a few moments. Getting data will require a _double_ JOIN then since there are three tables involved? Since the data is provided as an array i need to do a foreach loop on adding the separate records to the intermediary table if i onderstand correctly?

Comment: Yes a double join would be needed to get the `group` records associated to your user through the intermediary table. And yes, a foreach per record is an acceptable way to do it.